# What is the number of k length cycles in a grid graph with $n^2$ vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I was counting number of cycles in a grid graph with $n^2$ vertices. I know number of 4-cycles in  the grid graph will be $n^2$. What about cycles of any arbitrary length $k$. Is there any closed form formula to calculate that. If there is one, how do we arrive at that?

I am new to graph theory and combinatorics. I would very much appreciate answers with some explanations. Thank you!!

Comment: Actually, the number of 4-cycles in a grid graph with $n^2$ vertices is $(n-1)^2$. For the rest, see the [Wolfram website](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html).